# How to avoid duplicates in a database from a textfield in a form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, forms

I am sorry, this question has probably been asked before but I can't find any satisfying answer so here I go:

I have a web form. The user can enter a company name in a text field. The content of this text field is then used to check if this company already exists in the database with a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE company_name='textfieldContent';
```

If the query returns no result, the company is added in the database. The problem is that if some people write the company name differently (eg 'Company' and 'Company Ltd.') or write it with a typo, the query returns no result and I end up having several rows in my database referring to the same company.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent this ? Thanks.

The website was developed with Struts2 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add some front end validation to your web form to narrow things down a bit. You could instead of having a free text box have a drop down selection instead and then if the user cannot find the company name it gives them the option to add it in free text then.

You could code something to remove all the prefixes and suffixes but you would have a million edge cases that would ultimately be a pain to maintain.

Comment: There is already a drop down next to the text field (if the user chooses an element in the drop down, the value is immediately copied in the text field), but apparently most users find it more convenient to use the text field without even checking the dropdown

Comment: Can you change it so instead of having the field visible to begin with it only becomes visible if a user selects a specific option such as "Not found".

Comment: Wow, that's actually a very simple and yet effective solution. Thanks man :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to search with exact company name then you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE company_name LIKE '%textfieldContent%' LIMIT 1
```

Or you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE company_name LIKE '%textfieldContent%'
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to do at first, but it is not a good idea. Imagine two people from the same company but working in separated branches in France and Germany. One would work for Company SARL, the other one for Company GmbH. If the french one decides to register as 'Company SARL' and then the german one uses 'Company', then he would end up being affiliated with the french branch. So unfortunately, this solution is not good for me. But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: then you can show the result first before adding or deciding that would be more user-friendly.